# Julia Flux issue: UndefVarError: Tracker not defined

Tags: debugging, julia, flux.jl

I'm trying to run the sample code in https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/NeuralNetDiffEq.jl/blob/master/test/NNODE_tests.jl (first example on scalars) but am getting a `UndefVarError: Tracker not defined error`. I tried `using Flux.Tracker` and `using Tracker` but couldn't get it fixed. Has Tracker been deprecated? Or is it some compatibility issue? I'm using Flux v0.10.1 and Tracker 0.2.6. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they have switched from `Tracker` to `Zygote`, see [here](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/master/NEWS.md).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Downgrade to Flux v0.9 (which has Flux.Tracker) using `Pkg.add(Pkg.PackageSpec(;name="Flux", version="0.9.0"))`
2. Edit the NeuralNetDiffEq ODE solver jl files:

For solution 2, first use `using Pkg; Pkg.add("Tracker")`. Then do `import NeuralNetDiffEq; path(NeuralNetDiffEq)` to find the package path. Open ode_solver.jl (or whichever solver you are using), and then add `using Tracker` at the top of the file.

(Note as of Jan 16 2019, NeuralNetDiffEq doesn't completely work with Flux 0.10!)

Hope this will be useful to someone!